# Servlet won't respond on AJAX call; will when called from console

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I have the following ajax javascript.

My `js`:

```
  function updateCart() {
    var numRooms = $("input[name='rooms']").val();
    $.post("../ShoppingCart", {
      rooms: numRooms
    });
    checkCart();
  }

  function checkCart() {
    $.get("../CartSize", function(resp) {
      $('#cart').text(resp);
    });
  }
```

My `html`:

```
<button name="carryOn" onclick="updateCart()">Add to cart</button>
```

When clicking the button with the onclick="updateCart()" attribute, the servlet receives the request, but the response is blank. If I call the updateCart() function from the javascript console, I get a response with content. Why? Servlet is just using a PrintWriter from the HttpSession session of the response to write text.

I have also tried

```
function updateCart() {
var numRooms = $( "input[name='rooms']").val();
$.post( "../ShoppingCart", {
    rooms: numRooms
}, function() {
    checkCart();
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the html for the button? Are you *sure* the function is even called when the element is clicked? Off hand, I would recommend using an event handler like  `$('#some-button').click(updateCart());` instead of `onclick` but that wouldnt be the actual issue

Comment: <button name="carryOn" onclick="updateCart()">Add to cart</button>

Comment: And yes, I am sure. I've included println statements in the servlet, and the servlet is reached and called. The response is just empty when called from the button click. If called from the javascript console in firefox, the response is as expected.

Comment: .fail(function() {     alert( "error" );   }) can you please try adding this your function and see if there is any kind of error

Comment: Can you try this syntax: `$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '../ShoppingCart',
  data: {rooms: numRooms},
  success: function() {},
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(error);
  }
});`  and let us know if there is a console log, what are the values?

Comment: The ShoppingCart POST works great. It is the CartSize get in checkCart() that is causing the issue.

Comment: Do note that ajax is asynchronous, meaning that, in your code, `checkCart()` is called *before* the ajax response is received, if this is not what you want, you'll need to move `checkCart()` into the success function of your `$.post()` call like this `$.post("../ShoppingCart", { rooms: numRooms }, function(){checkCart();});`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well, please see the edit

Comment: Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/x.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/x.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/x.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/x.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/x.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/x.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 10 more… }   This shows up in the firefox web console when using the syntax suggested by DelightedD0D

Comment: @user3591541 this tells us that your code is generating an error on the server side. That console output should be for `console.log(xhr);` . What is the value for the `console.log(status);` and `console.log(error);` ?

Comment: Resolved. This issue was the button. Apparently, <button> refreshes the page when no action is specified. Changing to input type="button" fixes it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. This issue was the button. Apparently,  refreshes the page when no action is specified. Changing to input type="button" fixes it.

Comment: Or, <button type="button">.